# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 406 for URL

Tags: java, json, url

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 406 for URL:
>   https://aa09616289afe6a25ea1f7f6fbf12073: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@mfaisal1521.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/products.json
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)   at
>   javaapplication9.Send_HTTP_Request2.call_me(Send_HTTP_Request2.java:33)
>     at
>   javaapplication9.Send_HTTP_Request2.main(Send_HTTP_Request2.java:21)

myCode:

```
URL url = new URL("https://aa09616289afe6a25ea1f7f6fbf12073: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@mfaisal1521.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/products.json");  

BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String i;
    while ((i = read.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(i);
    read.close();
```

Comment: I test this API in postman , it give json file but it popup errors when i call from my java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Done this by using restfull API. Thanks Rahkumar

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://mfaisal1521.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/products/4517591449687.json")
  .method("GET", null)
  .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWEwOTYxNjI4OWFmZTZhMjVlYTFmN2Y2ZmJmMTIwNzM6c2hwcGFfZjVmZDQ3YTY1M2Q0OWQ2NmU4ODY0MzY1NzhjNTQxODc=").build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

Answer (score 1):

Guess some headers are missing in the request posted via java code.

Check in postman what are all the headers gets posted add the same headers in java code also (click headers/code link in Postman to view the headers gets parsed)